# calculation with group mean and/or match data frames of different length

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to add a column B in this data frame (df) where values are based on the group mean of A (the mean for each different ID). For example, B would be 10*mean(A) for each T.

```
ID  T   A
1   1   1.1
1   10  1.3
1   100 1.5
2   1   2.6
2   10  1.9
2   100 2.2
```

One idea could be to calculate the mean of A for each group (ID==1 and ID==2), store it in a new object, and then to use ID to match objects...

With plyr, we can get the group means of A:

```
A.mean <- ddply(df, "ID", summarise, mean(A))
```

But I'm still looking for matching df and A.mean, I don't know how to deal with their different length...

I'd be happy ;-) to get

```
ID  T   A   A.mean
1   1   1.1 1.3
1   10  1.3 1.3
1   100 1.5 1.3
2   1   2.6 2.233333333
2   10  1.9 2.233333333
2   100 2.2 2.233333333
```

and then to do df$B <- df$A.mean * 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ave`

```
  within(df, {A.mean=ave(A, ID, FUN=mean); B.mean=10*A.mean})[,c(1:3,5,4)]
 #  ID   T   A   A.mean   B.mean
 #1  1   1 1.1 1.300000 13.00000
 #2  1  10 1.3 1.300000 13.00000
 #3  1 100 1.5 1.300000 13.00000
 #4  2   1 2.6 2.233333 22.33333
 #5  2  10 1.9 2.233333 22.33333
 #6  2 100 2.2 2.233333 22.33333
```

Or

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df)[,A.mean:=mean(A), by="ID"][,B.mean:=10*A.mean]
 df
```

Or another way with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, c("A.mean", "B.mean") := { m = mean(A); list(m, m*10) }, by=ID]
```

Comment: @Arun, I was searching for this solution, but couldn't get the syntax correct.  thanks.

Comment: akrun, that's alright. I already appreciate your effort. Your's is not a bad solution at all.

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform` instead of `summarise`:

```
ddply(df, .(ID), transform, A.mean = mean(A), B = mean(A) * 10)
#  ID   T   A   A.mean        B
#1  1   1 1.1 1.300000 13.00000
#2  1  10 1.3 1.300000 13.00000
#3  1 100 1.5 1.300000 13.00000
#4  2   1 2.6 2.233333 22.33333
#5  2  10 1.9 2.233333 22.33333
#6  2 100 2.2 2.233333 22.33333
```

Or you could add the column B after the `ddply` call as in your question.

Note that `summarise` breaks the data down to 1 row per group (of ID in this case) while `transform` keeps the existing structure and, in this case, simply adds a new column of the same length.

Here's the equivalent `dplyr` code (will be faster if you're working with large datasets):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(A.mean = mean(A),
                B = A.mean*10)
```